# I've added JPanel to JFrame and it still isn't showing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So this question has been asked a lot, but I've searched through several of them and it seems that everyone is forgetting to add the panel to the frame. I have added the panel to my frame, but I still am not seeing my JPanel.

```
public class AddSomethingFrame extends JFrame{
private JFrame application;
JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel();

    public AddSomethingFrame(JFrame application) {
        super("Add");
        this.application = application;

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        placeComponents(viewPanel);
        viewPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(13, 25, 13, 25));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                application.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void placeComponents (JPanel panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        nameLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(nameLabel);

        JTextField nameText = new JTextField(20);
        nameText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(nameText);

        JLabel brandLabel = new JLabel("Brand");
        brandLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        panel.add(brandLabel);

        JTextField brandText = new JTextField(20);
        brandText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        panel.add(brandText);

        JLabel costLabel = new JLabel("Cost");
        costLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(costLabel);

        JTextField costText = new JTextField(20);
        costText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(costText);


        JButton storeGearButton = new JButton("Store");
        storeGearButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(storeGearButton);

        this.add(viewPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

}
```

I've tried moving around the setVisible for the JFrame and the JPanel. I've tried changing the sizes of each and I tried changing the BorderLayout of the panel, but nothing is working. Please help.

Comment: We often tell folks here that `panel.setLayout(null)` is dangerous code, but unfortunately not enough listen. Please be the exception and listen and believe. Understand also what this does to your JPanel's preferred size

Comment: Also where do you ask the panel to the gui?? Your main problem appears to be this, a somewhat careless error. You're adding the viewpanel but not the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid a "placeComponents(viewPanel)" construction and directly add the  "JPanle panel" elements to your JFrame that will make your code easier. Somthing like that:

```
public class AddSomethingFrame extends JFrame{
static JFrame application;
//JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel();

public AddSomethingFrame(JFrame application) {
super("Add");
//    this.application = application;

setBounds(300, 200, 1000, 200);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//    placeComponents(viewPanel);
//    viewPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 25, 2, 25));
//    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//    setResizable(true);
//    pack();
//    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
//    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
//        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
//            application.setVisible(true);
//            setVisible(false);
//            dispose();
//        }
//    });
//    setVisible(true);
//}
//
//    private void placeComponents (JPanel panel) {
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//        panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    nameLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(nameLabel);

    JTextField nameText = new JTextField(20);
    nameText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(nameText);

    JLabel brandLabel = new JLabel("Brand");
    brandLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
    panel.add(brandLabel);

    JTextField brandText = new JTextField(20);
    brandText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
    panel.add(brandText);

    JLabel costLabel = new JLabel("Cost");
    costLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(costLabel);

    JTextField costText = new JTextField(20);
    costText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(costText);


    JButton storeGearButton = new JButton("Store");
    storeGearButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(storeGearButton);

    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AddSomethingFrame app= new AddSomethingFrame(application);
    app.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: `AddSomethingFrame` is a JFrame. No need to pass it a reference to one. Remove `application`.